# Counter cache cross settings in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, counter-cache

I have following models: `Category`, `SubCategory`, `Product`, `User` and `CategoryPerUser`.

Below is corresponding ER diagram:

[image]

Here is a brief explanation of what I want to achieve:

- a product belongs to a sub_category which belongs to a category
- a user can upload many products
- in category_per_user, I want to keep user uploaded articles per category count

For now I wrote a method in Product model which updates `CategoryPerUser.products_count` whenever a user add a new product.

Is there a way to set this logic using `counter-cache` or `counter-culture` ?

Or should I change my ER ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Don't think there is an automated way, you can use `after_create -> { increase_counter }` in your Product model.

Comment: Is `CategoryPerUser` a physical table in the database? What columns does it have? And how do you plan to use this table?

Comment: @zanadto CategoryPerUser is a physical table. It just holds `category_id` , `user_id` and `products_count`. I just want to avoid counting a user products for a given category.

Comment: @user4523968 thanks. thats the way I am handling it now

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would prefer to use a database view. If you don't store a huge amount of data in the database, this will be a pretty simple and convenient solution.

The win of this solution is that you don't have to create an extra physical table in the database and don't have to run some callback every time you create/update records.

You will have a virtual table that will be created and populated only when you refer to the corresponding model. You just need to create suitable SQL query.

To read: [Using Postgres Views with Rails](https://roberteshleman.com/blog/2014/09/18/using-postgres-views-with-rails/)

Comment: thanks for the tips. I won't be having lot of data. Let me give it a try and check the performance @zanadto